# show to function javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to show a javascript function * outside * the tags  and , inside the tags work, but I need to be out of them.

How to pass?

My code PHP in WORDPRESS:

```
function custom_shortcode3() {
    $conecta3 = mysql_connect("localhost", "mcommerce", "kaishek") or print (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("mcommerc_whmcs", $conecta3) or print(mysql_error()); 
    function mysql_get_var3($query,$y=0){
           $res = mysql_query($query);
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
           mysql_free_result($res);
           $rec = $row[$y];
           return $rec;

    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <div id="show"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

                            function total() {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('#show').load('datatotaldeprodutos.php')
                }, 1000);
            };
        <?
    echo "total();"; //WORK BUT NOT APPEAR IN WORDPRESS
?>
        </script>
    </html>
    <?
    echo "total();"; //NOT WORKKK
    echo "test"; //WORK, APPEAR IN WORDPRESS. i need the function appear
    }
add_shortcode( 'totaldeprodutos', 'custom_shortcode3' );
```

Comment: _* outside * the tags_ ? What does that mean ?

Comment: echo "total();"; in the tags <script> and <html> work, mas not appear in my wordpress shortcode

Comment: You must have a condition in the `php` end...Could be easily differentiated using `query-string-parameter` => `$('#show').load('datatotaldeprodutos.php?ajax-call=true')`

Comment: I edited my post, the A please look

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding why you wouldn't just run the function in the JavaScript itself. PHP is a server-side language, and doesn't have access to functions you write in JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function total() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('datatotaldeprodutos.php')
        }, 1000);
    };

    total();  // run the function

</script>
```